# Android Studio SDKmanager Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, flutter, sdk

Currently I am trying to set up my Android Studio environment for Flutter and I am unable to update sdkmanager or else I would obtain the following errors :

[image: Error: Could not find or load main class]

This error affects the rest of my tools folder (sdkmanager,avdmanager, basically any .bat I run within that folder) as well.

**What I have tried:**

- Clean installed and reinstalled Android Studio numerous times
- Uninstalled and reinstalled Java numerous times (Version 13)
- Change parts of my sdkmanager.bat and android.bat based on the other stack overflow questions--since this did not work, I reverted them back to the original code
- Run as admin with command prompt and powershell
- Installed JDK 8 because Flutter doesn’t like other versions of Java
- Changed my environmental variables -these are the variables in relation to Android Studio and Java as of now

CLASSPATH - %JAVA_HOME%\lib;

JAVA_HOME - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1

PATH - C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Android;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Users[username]\Documents\flutter\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\git-cmd.exe;

**Updates**

For majority of the .bat files, %JAVA_OPTS% is causing the issue, I’ve tried to set a JAVA_OPTS variable but that does not help

**Solution**

I deleted %JAVA_OPTS% from the .bat file and it seems that was the issue, but I don’t think I’m supposed to delete that part.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `JAVA_OPTS` causes issues on using JDK versions lower than 11 as mentioned on this [issue thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/39549). Removing this should resolve the issue. Another workaround to prevent similar issues is to use the [JDK bundled](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#jdk) with Android Studio.